# Слово static в глобальной переменной не работает

Tags: синтаксис, c++

Вот что написано:

> Последнее использование static —
> глобальная переменная в файле кода. В
> этом случае использование static
> указывает, что исходный код в других
> файлах, которые являются частью
> проекта, не может получить доступ к
> переменной. Только код внутри того же
> файла может увидеть переменную (её
> область видимости ограничена файлом).
> Эта техника может быть использована
> для моделирования
> объектно-ориентированного кода, потому
> что она ограничивает видимость
> переменных и таким образом помогает
> избежать конфликта имен.

Но это не работает. Завожу статическую переменную в отдельном заголовке (например, `static int i = 0;`) и свободно получаю к ней доступ из main-функции, хотя эти коды в разных файлах. В чем подвох?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы объявляете `static int i = 0;` в заголовочном файле, а потом подключаете этот файл в двух модулях, то глобальная переменная `i` будет в обоих модулях, но для каждого модуля своя. Переменную нужно объявлять не в заголовочном файле, а именно в нужном модуле.

Comment: те это будут не зависимые дубликаты? правильно? (в моем примере)

Comment: @perfect, да, независимые друг от друга переменные.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший человек.

Comment: Добавлю, что в современном C++ для этих целей (независимая, не видимая в других модулях глобальная переменная) принято использовать _анонимные namespace'ы_:

    namespace
    {
        int i = 0;
    }